# Hom( , ) and Hom_F( , ) and tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, group-homomorphism, free-groups, module-isomorphism

My professor said in his lecture, "For Abelian groups $A$, $B$, $C$ and field $F$ $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)=\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} (A, B)$ but $\operatorname{Hom}(C, F) \neq \operatorname{Hom}_F (C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} F, F)$ in general, the equality holds when $C$ is free." Where $\operatorname{Hom}(,)$ contains all of the group homomorphism and $\operatorname{Hom}_F(,)$ contains all F-linear maps.

I can easily see that the former is right since Abelian groups are naturally $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. I'm new to the tensor product, so for the latter, I can't understand what's going on. Why is $C\otimes F$ an $F$-module and why does the equality hold when $C$ is free? Can you also give me an example when $C$ is not free and the equality doesn't hold?

Comment: Quick tip: for "Hom" use the command `\operatorname{Hom}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The $F$-module multiplication on $C\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ is given by $a (e\otimes b)=e\otimes (ab)$ for $a,b \in F$ and $e\in C$.
- When $C$ is free, if $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $C$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $\{e_i \otimes 1_F\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $C\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ as an $F$-module.  Note that $F$ is a field, so an $F$-module is always free, but when $C$ is free, there is a basis of this special form.
- Tensoring $C$ with a field $F$ of characteristic zero kills off all torsion elements in $C$.

Edit:
According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings) $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(C, F)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_F (C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} F, F)$ as $F$-modules for any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C$ (read the last section "Relation between the extension of scalars and the restriction of scalars".)

Comment: So if my understanding is correct. The two groups are always isomorphic no matter whether $C$ is free.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I don't know why your Professor said that.  There's map $C \rightarrow C \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ that sends $x$ to $x \otimes 1_F$, and this induces a pullback from $\operatorname{Hom}_F (C\otimes_\mathbb{Z} F, F)$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(C, F)$ by composition.  The pullback is always an isomorphism of $F$ modules.  The latter is given a structure of $F$-module by multiplication on the range of a function.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!